# Database schema about social networking like Facebook

Tags: database, facebook, database-design, social-networking

Like Facebook, I have posts, comments and user profiles.

**I THINK THAT**

> - Posts and comments **do not** need the details of user
> - **ONLY** user profiles need the details

So I separate the user information into **main** and **detail**

Here is the schema.

[image: schema]

**Question**

> Is it necessary to separate user data into **main** and **details**?
>
> **WHY** not or **WHY** yes?

Thanks for applying!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using separate tables because you may not need all that information at one time. You could do it either way but I think of it as do you need all of the data at once.

**Table 1 (User Auth)**

This table would hold only information for log-in and have three columns (**user_name**, **hashed_password**, **UID**)

So your query would select **UID** where **user_name** and **hashed_password** matched. I would also recommend never storing a readable password in a database table because that can become a security issue.

**Table 2 (Basic Information)**

This table would hold the least amount of information that you would get at signup to make a basic profile. The fields would consist of **UID**, **name**, **DOB**, **zip**, **link_to_profile_photo**, **email** and whatever basic information you would like.  **email** is kind of special because if you require the **user_name** to be an email address there is no reason to have it twice.

**Table 3 (Extended Information)**

This table would hold any optional information that the user could enter like **phone_number**, **bio** or **address** assigned by **UID**.

Then after that you can add as many other tables that you would like. One for Post, one for comments, ect.

An Example of a Post table would be like:

**post_id**, **UID**, **the_post**, **date_of_post**, **likes**, ect.

Then for Comments

**comment_id**, **for_post_id**, **UID**, **the_comment**, **date_of_comment**, **likes**, ect.

Breaking it down in to small sections would be more efficient in the long run.

Comment: Some of basic information need only when I load my personal profile, should I separate them into another table?

Comment: Yes you could just add that to the extended information table. The basic information should be the most common used data. So like if every page of your site will have the users name and a profile photo then you would want to have that in the basic table.

Answer (score 0):

Database performance is associated with disk seek time. Disk seek time is a bottleneck of database performance. For large table, you may need large seek time to locate and read an entry. As for post and comments you do not need user details, just user main info, you may get reduced read time when you read only user Id for post and comments. Also joins with user_main_info will be faster. You may keep the smallest portion of data you need to read most frequently on one table and other detailed information on another table. But, in a scenario like when you will always need to read all the user information together, this won't give you any benefit.

Answer (score -2):

1)the userinformation table will be added

```
ex:create table fb_users
(intuserid primary key,
username varchar(50),
phoneno int,
emailid varchar(max))
```

2)the sending of the friend request would be

2.a)create the table name called friends, friend requestor, friend requested by, status b/w both of them, Active flag

```
ex:create table fb_friends
(intfriendid primary key,
intfriendrequestor int (foreign key with fb_users's(intuserid)),
intfriendrequestedby int (foreign key with fb_users's(intuserid)),
statusid varchar(max)(use the status id from the below table which is a look up table),

active bit)
```

3)creating the table for the status the status

3.a)create the table name called status, statusname, statusdesc, Active flag

```
ex:create table fb_staus
(intstatusid primary key,
statusname varchar,
statusdesc varchar,
active bit)
```

the status could be

pending
approval
deleted
..etc

4)similarly  for creating the groups,likes,comments also

a table will be created respectively for each one of them and the foreign key of the intuserid from user table 
are linked for each of them